# How can I have text inside a bbcode?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, bbcode

I need help with this preg_match script. I want to have a text that is inside a bbcode. So this would be the string: `[caption id="attachment_123" align="alignleft" width="100" caption="This is the text that I want"]`

How would you do this? The important thing is also, that the values like id and align wont be the same all the time. I tried something like `preg_match('#\[caption(?:.*?)caption=\"(.*?)\"\]#s',$result,$array);`

Thank you for your help!
phpheini

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Replace `[` and `]` to `<` and `>` then convert that string to XML object using `SimpleXML` and access `caption` as a property of created object.

```
$input  = '[caption id="attachment_123" align="alignleft" width="100" caption="This is the text that I want"]';
$input  = str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('<', '>'), $input);

$object = new SimpleXML($input);

echo $object->caption;
```

Clean and easy. `Regexp` and `HTML`/`BBCode` is painful.

Comment: If I am not wrong what this does is giving me the text between the caption elements. But thats not what I want.

Comment: I don't think that would be a proper solution. Just think what will `[script src="http://attacker-site.com/attack.js"][/script]` do.

Comment: So do you have another way or do you know what is wrong with my script? I dont get why it doesnt work.